# How to test website for large screens?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, browser, screen-resolution

I want to test website for large screens such as 1920 x 1080 pixels, 2560 x 1600 pixels, In browserstack i find only 1280 x 1024 pixels is maximum for windows machines, Is there any website to test for large screen resolutions

Comment: Well… you could zoom out.

Comment: "1280 x 1024 pixels is maximum for windows machines"... Huh? Mine is 1920 x 1200?

Comment: @MarjanVenema, I mentioned resolution available in browserstack

Comment: @M.R: Don't understand. Why would that be different? Browser resolutions are dictated by the platforms on which they run? When I run my browser full screen, it definitely has 1920x1200 available?

Comment: This one is great (just to add to another people responses): http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: @MarjanVenema he's simply talking about options available in browserstack. It is not a statement about the capabilities of various operating systems. Edit: I misunderstood the first time I read it too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well you can easily do it in Mozilla Firefox.

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Then you can choose from varieties of resolutions, also for your custom resolutions.

You can drag the sides to increase and decrease the resolutions.

[image]

Some links here on keyboard shortcuts and responsive design view

[Keyboard shortcuts on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts)

[Responsive Design View on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View)

and the other on [tilt](http://blog.mozilla.org/tilt/) which I guess you have it as an add-on and that is conflicting with the command.

---

For one time you you have to drag for custom **`2560x1600`** resolution and add it as preset. Then further you can always use this resolution settings.

[image]

Comment: Although I like the screenshot, ctrl+shift+m gives me the 3d-look instead of being able to choose resolution.

Comment: you have installed tilt. Try disabling the tilt addon later on you can unable it. I have added some links in answers check out that as well.

Comment: Without checking, tilt is now standard in Firefox and you don't need the add-on unless that changed very recently.

Comment: I don't have tilt in my Firefox, I have most recent version..:)

Comment: On Google Chrome and IIRC Internet Explorer zoom shortcuts are Ctrl-+ and Ctrl-- (Ctrl-Plus and Ctrl-Min).

Comment: @Gaurav, how can i test 2560 x 1600 pixels?

Comment: You can drag and set that resolution for one time, then set it as preset. You will have this for further testing also.

Comment: my pleasure..:)

Comment: The problem of using this feature is that font sizes don't change! ;).

Comment: Responsive design view is also available under Menu > Developer > Responsive Design View.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you test 2560 x 1600 pixels or wider pixels it will same for the Full HD resolutions that mean 1920x1080 , so your site is responsive and supports up to full HD no matter the how screen size changes.  If you want to test in multiple devices, you can use a few testers and the Firefox browser mobile tester.

("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobilerwd-ester/elmekokodcohlommfikpmojheggnbelo")

( "http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/" )

RESPONSIVE DESIGN TESTING TOOL - ("http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/")

Comment: http://designmodo.com/responsive-test/